# How do I create a dialog with multiple text fields using zenity?

Tags: bash, command-line, gui, zenity

I want to crate a GUI for some command line programs and I need to get info from multiple text fields e.g. 'Username', 'Password' and a checkbox 'Sign automatically?'.

I need to set particular variables in my script equal to the respective text fields' input by the user e.g. `user`, `pass`, `login`. Also it would have an OK button and a Quit button.

How can I realise this this? I searched online and I was able to find only examples with one text field?

Answer (score 11):

Basically, you can use multi-entry forms using Zenity. A form can be built using text fields, password fields, and calendars. Text fields can be added with the `--add-entry` flag. Password fields are added with the `--add-password` flag, and calandars are added with the `--add-calendar` flag.

```
 $ zenity --forms --title="Create user" --text="Add new user" \
   --add-entry="First Name" \
   --add-entry="Last Name" \
   --add-entry="Username" \
   --add-password="Password" \
   --add-password="Confirm Password" \
   --add-calendar="Expires"
```

Zenity form

[Here](http://jamesslocum.com/post/55694754191) is a tutorial that might help you out.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Is that better @HalosGhost and if so then can you up vote

Comment: This looks *much* better. However, if you got the idea from the page you linked to originally, you should still include the link as a source reference.

Comment: What? <filler text>

Comment: I no longer have the link@HalosGhost

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20254/discussion-between-halosghost-and-jhondoe).

Comment: the output of the fields values is quite simple, a string separated by '|', sequentially related to the fields order; I came here looking for the meaning of "--forms", zenity is really useful for the majority of simple (and even not that simple) GUI requirements. From what I read, [yad](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/12/yad-zenity-on-steroids-display.html) can do even more, but not that many ppl seem to have it, but is simple to add the repository too.

Answer (score 2):

I do not believe you can do this using Zenity. It's meant for simple GUI's and isn't really a full fledged GUI environment. You'll either have to change the flow of your tool or use GTK+ directly to get your desired results.

Comment: do you believe the extra functionalities of [yad](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/12/yad-zenity-on-steroids-display.html) could suffice? as the questioner stated, it is for command line programs, and so, that extra complexity is certainly not required.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
yad --form \
    --field User "" \
    --field Password:H "" \
    --field "Sign Automatically?":CHK FALSE
```

Comment: the question have "using zenity"

Comment: YAD is a superb zenity fork. Can you solve this question using zenity? Is there a way to put a checkbox on the zenity form? Of course not, but how you can see is very simple to do it using YAD. And that’s why YAD is called zenity on steroids